# Did Google Maps stop working in IE8 in late 2014?

Tags: google-maps

Google maps in IE8 now appears to generally look like this (checked several machines):

[image]

I'm fairly sure it worked a few weeks ago. But googling for the problem only shows up a 2012 news item about Google withdrawing support for IE8. It has definitely worked more recently than that. But can't see any recent info on this topic.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but this probably has to do with the move away from what Google now calls "Classic Maps" to whatever they call the new thing. Probably the new thing just won't run on IE8. Classic Maps disappeared as an option for me a couple of weeks ago. (And there was much sorrow.)

Comment: Hm... on this machine, it seems to be back. Try this link: https://maps.google.com/maps?output=classic&dg=opt

Comment: Google only supports the last to versions of any browser.  This has been their policy for awhile now.  While they don't support it, in the past older versions do work with their services, but at any time they can stop working and Google has no problems doing that.

Comment: @Ramhound I accept that and my question contains zero complaining. I am just asking whether the community knows when it happened and whether it's officially broken as of now

Comment: @JamieHanrahan not for me on that link

Comment: @hawbsl - The problem is.  Question about web applications like Google Maps are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.  The fact the problem is stemmed from using IE8 isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [this Google support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33864?hl=en):

> As previously announced, Internet Explorer 11 launched on October 17, 2013, and as a result, we've discontinued support for Internet Explorer 9.
>
> Organizations that depend on old versions of Internet Explorer may want to consider a dual browser strategy.

When Google [discontinued IE8 support in 2012](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-apps-pulls-plug-on-ie-8-windows-xp-left-out-in-the-cold/), that was specific to Google Apps: Gmail, Google Drive, etc.

Also remember that dropping support does **not** necessarily mean "everything will break tomorrow".

---

My personal recommendation is to take Google's advice and "consider a dual browser strategy". Switch users to Chrome or Firefox and deploy apps specific for intranet sites, etc. that use an embedded IE control.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Running Google Maps in compatibility view fixes the issue for me.

You can do this by either clicking the compatibility view icon next to the address bar, or by adding google.com to the compatibility view settings.